# Typescript definition of dynamic object with dynamic keys

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

I got data from an external interface and the data structure is kind of strange. I am trying to build a typescript interface for it.

```
{
   "userIds": {
        "431a87306b4bcba4": {
          "user_name": "JonDoe",
          "first_name": "Jon",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "name": "JonDoe"
        },
        "141a87306b4bcba4": {
          "user_name": "JonDoe2",
          "first_name": "Jon2",
          "last_name": "Doe2",
          "name": "JonDoe2"
        }
      }
}
```

My idea was this, but I think it is not correct.

```
export class Data {
  userIds: Dic;
}

interface Dic {
  [key: string]: User
}

export class User {
  user_name: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  name: string;
}
```

Would be glad if one of you type experts could help me - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`Record<string, User>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

```js
export interface Data {
  userIds: Record<string, User>;
}

export interface User {
  user_name: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  name: string;
}

const data: Data = {
  userIds: {
    "431a87306b4bcba4": {
      user_name: "JonDoe",
      first_name: "Jon",
      last_name: "Doe",
      name: "JonDoe",
    },
    "141a87306b4bcba4": {
      user_name: "JonDoe2",
      first_name: "Jon2",
      last_name: "Doe2",
      name: "JonDoe2",
    },
  },
};
```

Please note: What you have posted here is not valid JSON and not a valid JS object so I have added `{}` around that to make it a valid object.

```json
"userIds": {
        "431a87306b4bcba4": {
          "user_name": "JonDoe",
          "first_name": "Jon",
          "last_name": "Doe",
          "name": "JonDoe"
        },
        "141a87306b4bcba4": {
          "user_name": "JonDoe2",
          "first_name": "Jon2",
          "last_name": "Doe2",
          "name": "JonDoe2"
        }
      }
```